# How to infer the type of a CSV file from contents or headers?

Tags: design

We've got a few CSV file templates with different set of headers. In each CSV template there's at least one unique header and each template is meant for a different entity in the system.

Right now, when the user wants to upload a CSV file, the user choses which type of a CSV it is from a dropdown, so that on the backend we know how to validate it. However it's really annoying having to choose the type of the CSV file all the time as you can upload a couple of CSVs at a time.

We'd like to infer the type of the CSV on the backend without having the user choose it from the UI, however I am not quite sure how to approach that.

One problem that came to my mind is, we can not rely on checking headers because some of the required headers might be missing for any reason. As the headers are missing, we can't infer the type to tell the user that some headers are missing because we don't even know what type of a CSV they meant to upload.

As a solution I thought we could just compare the missing header numbers against all the templates we have and decide that the type they meant is the one with the least number of missing headers possible, but I am not sure whether that makes any sense.

Another option I thought about is using some kind of ML so that we can get probabilities of a file being of a certain type. In this case I am not sure whether this is an overkill or whether it's possible.

Cheers!

Comment: *"some of the required headers might be missing for any reason"* -- this is what causes increased complexity for your problem. Without standardized headers, you are essentially working with schema-less data. Are end users creating CSV files in a spreadsheet program? Why not require the user to specify the required headers?

Comment: Well, we have the templates with the headers ready for people to use on Google sheets but you never know how they will actually try to upload things. That's why I said "for any reason" :D. They should be using the templates, most of the time the required headers will be there. How would they know what headers are required and how would we tell them what headers are required if we don't know what type of a CSV they meant to upload?

Comment: Well, on second thought, I think I get what you mean now. So basically return an error for all the CSV files that don't have required headers and let the user figure out what headers they are missing as it will be easier for them to figure that out,which will make things easier. Moreover, I guess trying to infer the type of a CSV which doesn't even have required headers doesn't make much sense and trying to infer the type at that point doesn't bring value.

Comment: I deleted my previous comments and added an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to infer the template based on the headers, when some of the headers are missing, means the application will be making assumptions about the data structure uploaded by end users. Based on this assumed structure, your application will load data into your system. If data gets put in the wrong places (tables, files, etc), you will need additional logic that allows people to correct bad data.

Instead, validate that headers in the uploaded CSV file match headers from one of the templates. If the headers in the uploaded file do not match one of your predefined templates, show an error message to the user. Ideally, the error message should include a link allowing the user to choose from the list of predefined templates that do conform to your expectations.

Without some assurance about data structure, the application will have a difficult and error-prone time deciding where that data should be stored.

This extends beyond headers in a CSV file and can also be applied to individual values in a row. Consider the case where a column requires a date value, but the user enters `2022-02-29` — 2022 is not a leap year, so February only has 28 days, not 29.

Rather than adding complex logic to guess what the data structure is, add validation logic upon uploading the file ensuring the CSV conforms to one of your expectations. That way this becomes part of the validation routine. Once the structure is validated, individual rows and columns can be validated using the same basic work flow for the end user.

Comment: This exapresses mostly what I thought when I read the question. I would actually implement this way: when the user wants to upload, lets say, 20 CSV files, the system shows a list with 20 rows where the system displays in each line which file was classified as which type, and for which the classification failed. Each line should contain a dropdown where the chosen header type is displayed and might be changed (with a type "unknown" for the unclasfied files). The user can then pick the missing header types and start the import with one click on the Ok "button".

Answer (score 3):

You don't need sophisticated machine learning to do this. ML is essentially just systematic similarity computation, and computing the similarity between sets of strings (the headers of a file) is simple. I'd think that either of a number of easy options would work well:

- count how many headers are in common with each of the templates you're prepared to handle
- count how many *values* in the input occur in a representative sample of values of each template type
- if the actual handling is cheap, simply try to parse the input as each type of template in turn, and choose the result that contains the largest amount of valid data.

Comment: Regarding the first option, I had not thought about counting the common headers instead of the missing ones. Good idea.
Regarding the second option, could you please elaborate it a bit more? I didn't really get what you meant.
Regarding the third option, I think in my case that would be more complex as I don't know yet how the validation works for creating entities. For me, the bestion options seems to be the first one.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a sample of previously submitted CSV files. Simply count the values in the samples of each type, and then check how many of those samples reappear in the currently submitted content.